# Searching Array for a Value

Tags: ruby

I am trying to search an Array for a value, if that value is found then return that the value is found and the index at which it was found. If the value is not found then the index returned is -1

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
search_value = gets.chomp
array.map.include?(search_value) || -1

if index != -1
puts "Found " + search_value + " at " + index.to_s
```

The expected result is `Found 2 at 1` instead I receive `Found 2 at True`, I understand why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-index), which returns `nil` in case the value is not part of the array.

To return `-1` when the value is not found:

```
index = array.index(search_value) || -1
```

Comment: Why the `map`? IMO it is useless in this case and actually makes every think slower.

Comment: @spickermann you're right, didn't notice it. Just copied the line @HKeys34 had and changed `include?` to `index`. Updating it...

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use [array.index(element)](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index)

Example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.index(5) || -1 # returns 4 (because 5 is at 4th index)
array.index(6) || -1 # returns -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
array = ["1", "2", "3"]
search_value = gets.chomp
index = array.index(search_value) || -1
puts "Found " + search_value + " at " + index.to_s
// Type 2
// Expected output: Found 2 at 1
```

I don't know why `array = [1, 2, 3]` doesn't work correctly but I try `array = ["1", "2", "3"]` instead it works. Hope someone can explain a little bit.

Comment: You need to convert the `search_value` into Integer with `to_i`, so you can have them as int the array too.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7GoKLFSwVYh2lBHwUhHwTiWqzg1sSg5I74sMac0FSiRnlpSrJeckZ9boFeSH5/JlZmXkloBFAdr1APzNJC1aCrU1CjoGnIVlJYUKyi55ZfmpSgoKWgrIKsBmVQMFFNSSCwBS4KNAYv@/28EAA "Ruby – Try It Online")